# Group sum by day + pair_id if data in db has timezone offset

Tags: postgresql, date, group-by, timestamp, timezone

I have a server that gives me some information grouped by day ( I use `date_trunc()` for it). Because of the timezone I know that `2020-06-06 21:00:00` in my DB is actually `2020-06-07 00:00:00`. 
I need to count sum of column meta, grouped by `(tm + pair_id)`, but because of offset data from db that has `2020-06-06 21:00` tm doesn't sum with other `2020-06-07` data. As a result instead of total amount per `day+pair_id` I have few rows with the same `tm` and `pair_id` (because `2020-06-06 21:00` became `2020-06-07 00:00` in the result)

Can I fix grouping here without creating subrequests?

I have table:

```
   CREATE TABLE tests.tbl (
    id int4 NULL,
    tm timestamp NULL,
    meta float4 NULL,
    pair_id int4 NULL
);
```

With this data in it:

[image]

My query is:

```
SELECT 
    pair_id,
    date_trunc('day', min(tm) at time zone '3' at time zone 'UTC') as tm,
    sum(meta)
FROM tests.tbl
WHERE (tm BETWEEN '2020-06-06 21:00:00+00:00:00' AND '2020-06-08 20:59:00+00:00:00')
group by pair_id, tm
order by tm, pair_id;
```

My result is:

[image]

Expected result is:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the logic you want is:

```
SELECT 
    pair_id,
    date_trunc('day', tm at time zone '3' at time zone 'UTC') as tm,
    sum(meta)
FROM tests.tbl
WHERE tm BETWEEN '2020-06-06 21:00:00+00:00:00' AND '2020-06-08 21:00:00+00:00:00'
GROUP BY 1, 2
ORDER BY 2, 1;
```

That is: the `select` and `group by` clause should be consistent (in particular, the timestamp column should be offset in both clauses).

It might be simpler to understand if you move the offset to a subquery:

```
SELECT pair_id, date_trunc('day', tm) as tm, sum(meta)
FROM (
    SELECT 
        pair_id,
        tm at time zone '3' at time zone 'UTC' as tm,
        meta
    FROM tests.tbl
) t
WHERE tm >= '2020-06-07'::date AND tm < '2020-06-09'::date
GROUP BY 1, 2
ORDER BY 2, 1;
```

Comment: The first query has wrong result - sums are 9 and 13, so it doesn't sum with 2020-06-06 21:00. Second one has correct result, but it's subquery... Btw, what does 'GROUP BY 1, 2' mean? What is 1 and 2 here? Numbers of columns?

Comment: @Mitch: `1` and `2` refer to the number of the columns in the `SELECT` clause. So for example in the second query, `1` is `pair_id`, `2` is `date_trunc('day', tm)`.

Comment: Thanks, never used this before

Comment: Changed where in your first query to ' tm between '2020-06-06 21:00:00+00:00:00'and '2020-06-08 21:00:00+00:00:00' and it seems to work all right

Comment: @Mitch: ok I changed that part of my answer accordingly.

Comment: Plese, add ' here:  AND '2020-06-08 21:00:00+00:00:00 for working out of the box